# Have exception hibernate.properties not found

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I tried to configure my hibernate and have this error. I checked all answers on stackoverflow but they did't help. I put cfg file into resources but it did't help.

```
public class Dbconnect {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

              StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").build();     

           Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry )
                   .addAnnotatedClass( UserProfile.class )
                   .getMetadataBuilder()
                   .applyImplicitNamingStrategy( ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.INSTANCE )
                    .build();

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();


        }
    }
```

**my project structure**

[image]

**my cfg file**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytestdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

upd.
Added mvn depedencies and have time zone error.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**error**:

```
    окт. 15, 2018 3:19:44 ПП org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.6.Final}
окт. 15, 2018 3:19:44 ПП org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/C:/Users/12/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.0/jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
ERROR: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is at path `src/main/resources`; when maven builds the project, that path will be (by default) at the root of the classpath, so to load it in your context, you should use:

```
new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml")
```

EDIT

The new stacktrace shows that the xml file is now found after your change above; unfortunately it couldn't be parsed because of a missing library (jaxb).

Change your pom.xml with the following to add the dependendcy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, my xml file is at path src/main/resources. When i tried  new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml")

Comment: i have error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
 at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$1.initialize(ConfigLoader.java:41)
 at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$1.initialize(ConfigLoader.java:38)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.ValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolder.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)

Comment: That means the xml file has been found, but it couldn't be parsed because of a missing dependency (jaxb). Which version of JDK are you trying to use?

Comment: (please update your question, with new stacktraces or changes you made, instead of using comments)

Comment: i updated question with new stacktraces, i use jdk 10

Comment: thanks, updated my answer too with another needed change

Comment: yes,it helps,but i have time zone error, i will try to fix this bu myself.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow; you can mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you, and vote on it if you liked it. Also read the https://stackoverflow.com/tour